# Is there a JS short syntax for setting maximum or minimum limit of a value

Tags: javascript, max, limit, minimum

If I want to limit a value between a min and max, today I use somthing like that :

```
if (level > 100) level = 100;
if (level < 0) level = 0;
```

I'm quite sure that there should be a more elegant/fastest method to do that. 
If yes, what could it be ?

Comment: Maybe `level = level > 100  ? 100 : (level < 0 ? 0 : level)`...

Comment: `level = Math.max(0, Math.min(level, 100));`

Comment: define *"elegant"* ... depends on your preference for easy to read declarative code vs shorter not so intuitive code

Comment: If you can use lodash, then it provides a function to do this called `_.clamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var level = level > 100 ? 100 : (level < 0 ? 0 : level)
```

It's called **Conditional Statement**, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for more informations...